# system.data.enumerablerowcollection to List<T>, in run time

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
List<string> values_ofColumn = MasterDataTableObject.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>(ColumnName)).Distinct().ToList<string>();
```

i am using above Query to read All Values of a specific column from a Data Table.
if if i wanna read all the columns ,i have to handle all the cases

```
foreach (string ColumnName in AllColumns)
{
    List<string> values_ofColumn = null;
    if (MasterDataTableObject.Columns[ColumnName].DataType.Name.ToString() == "String")
    {
        values_ofColumn = MasterDataTableObject.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>(fieldAttribute)).Distinct().ToList<string>();
    }
    if (MasterDataTableObject.Columns[ColumnName].DataType.Name.ToString() == "Double")
    {
        values_ofColumn = MasterDataTableObject.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<double>(fieldAttribute).ToString()).Distinct().ToList<string>();
    }
    if (MasterDataTableObject.Columns[ColumnName].DataType.Name.ToString() == "DateTime")
    {
        values_ofColumn = MasterDataTableObject.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<DateTime>(fieldAttribute).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).Distinct().ToList<string>();
    }
}
```

why i added lot of if else statements is...
i was unable to inscribe `MasterDataTableObject.Columns[ColumnName].DataType` in `Field<T>`
i know,it is compile time mapping.

is there any way i can get rid off from using if else

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string ColumnName in AllColumns)
{
    List<string> values_ofColumn = null;
    var coll =  (
                                from row in MasterDataTableObject.AsEnumerable()
                                select row[ColumnName]
                );
    values_ofColumn = coll.Select(row => row.ToString()).Distinct().ToList<string>();
}
```